# TypeScript 2.9 resolveJsonModule throws exception on transpiled files

Tags: json, typescript

I am using TypeScript 2.9's resolveJsonModule feature, which works fine as long as I use ts-node to execute the application. When I transpile the source files into my outdir it does also copy the JSON files into the outdir and puts a source map link to the type files into it, like this:

```
[
    {
        "scid": 59000000
    },
    {
        "scid": 59000000
    }

]
//# sourceMappingURL=roles.json.map
```

When I run my transpiled javascript files tries to parse these JSON files and obviously they throw a SyntaxError because of an unexpected token which points to the comment line:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: C:\Users\user\Documents\project\lib\assets\filename.json: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 22186
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

**My project root looks like this after transpilation**

- assets
- lib

  - assets
  - json-file.d.ts
  - json-file.json
  - src

    - all my transpiled js files and their d.ts files
- src

  - all my typescript source files
    tsconfig.json

**My question:**

How can I use TypeScript 2.9's resolveJsonModule feature so that the transpiled javascript is capable of parsing my JSON files (which currently does not work due to the comment line)?

**Edit:**

I already tried to put the assets folder into tsconfig.json's exclude property which didn't work. Full tsconfig.json content is here: https://ghostbin.com/paste/sdkcj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that this is an bug which had been fixed with TypeScript 2.9.2. The versions 2.9.0 and 2.9.1 added source maps to the transpiled JSON files.